# Swipe to get message details in chat using flutter

Tags: flutter, swipe, flutter-design

How can we add a function where we can Swipe the particular message to get message details like time and date in chat using flutter language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dismissible widget to wrap the widget :

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html

Dismissible allow you to ask confirmation or not.